# Transforming a data frame such that labels in a row are converted to column and aggregated

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, multilabel-classification

I need to get my data in a specific representation for a multi label classification.

I have a df such that :

```
Key Name             Description               Label
1   Self service    We want self service.      Performance
1   Self service    We want self service.      Storage
2   Multi cloud     Mutli cloud is needed.     Scaling
3   Storage issues  Storage upgrade.           Storage
```

I want to transform it to :

```
Key  Name             Description              Performance   Storage   Scaling
1    Self service    We want self service.         1            1         0
2    Multi cloud     Mutli cloud is needed.        0            0         1
3    Storage issues  Storage upgrade.              0            1         0
```

I have tried things with groupby, pivot and merge but can't get to a workable solution.

Any tricks that could help ?

I tried to pd.get_dummies and groupby but unable to combine them.

Comment: @MattDMo thank you. Just updated it, hope it's a legible form now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pivot_table`:

```
out = (df.pivot_table(index=['Key Name', 'Description'],
                      columns='Label', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
         .rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index())
print(out)

# Output
         Key Name             Description  Performance  Scaling  Storage
0     Multi cloud  Mutli cloud is needed.            0        1        0
1    Self service   We want self service.            1        0        1
2  Storage issues        Storage upgrade.            0        0        1
```